# ao apertar enter, o cmd abre porem fecha mesmo nao completando todos os comandos

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main (void)

{
    int valor1,valor2,soma,sub,mult,di;


    printf("Digite um numero inteiro: ");
    scanf("%d\n",valor1);

    printf("Digite outro numero inteiro: ");
    scanf("%d\n",valor2);

    soma = valor1 + valor2;
    sub = valor1 - valor2;
    mult = valor1 * valor2;
    di = valor1 / valor2; 

    printf("Valor da soma de %d + %d = %d\n",valor1,valor2,soma);
    printf("Valor da subtracao de %d + %d = $d\n",valor1,valor2,sub);
    printf("Valor da multiplicacao de %d * %d = %d\n",valor1,valor2,mult);
    printf("Valor da divisão de %d / %d = %d\n",valor1,valor2,di);


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

meu comando ta assim, porem sempre que executo, pega apenas o primeiro numero e simplesmente fecha(obs: sou novo na programação) [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Você está esquecendo de fazer o uso do '&' no scanf...

```
..., &valor1) ...
..., &valor2) ...
```

ps: também possui uma formatação errada no seu segundo printf(), basta substituir o char $ por %.